# Is there a way to get change log ("What's new") for my app from Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, app-store

I want to show the change log of the last update in my app.
Is there API or a way to get those changes that appear on the Appstore in "What's new" section?

I would prefer this way to rolling my own server code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the text shown on the App Store using the iTunes Search API

## overview:

https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html
*note that the example focuses on music! check out the code & the returned json to get the fields*

## my objc implementation:

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils/tree/master/DDUtils-Common/model/DDAppStoreInfo%20%5Bios%2Bosx%5D
*note that the code is NOT complete. the search returns a lot more info than what I use. Just use the right attribute*

## disclaimer

the objC code is my own implementation but I post it here as it serves to answer the question

Comment: The upper one doesn’t take you to any example code just a main landing page

Comment: are we talking about the same link even ;) I see examples en masse: "Searching the iTunes Store, Search Examples, Lookup Examples" :: "to search for all Jack Johnson audio and video content (movies, podcasts, music, music videos, audiobooks, short films, and tv shows), your URL would look like the following:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson"

Comment: Ok I see, I thought you intended to link directly to an example. So the bottom link is giving me a 404, the main repo exists though just not that specific page linked.